# How to pass a fastapi response as input to another function

Tags: python, opencv, fastapi

I  have a post request that simply takes camera addresses from clients, Now I want to pass the response from this post request to another function that does the streaming via a web socket.

how can I pass the post-request function as input to `get_stream` ?

**Post request function to take camera address**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect
from pydantic import BaseModel
import cv2
import uvicorn
app = FastAPI()

class Address(BaseModel):
    camera_id: Union[str, int] = 0 

@app.post("/camera_id")
async def address(address: Address):
    print(type(address.camera_id))
    print('----------------------')
    webcam = address.camera_id.isnumeric() or address.camera_id.endswith('.txt') or address.camera_id.lower().startswith(
        ('rtsp://', 'rtmp://', 'http://', 'https://'))
    
    if webcam:
        return address
    else:
        return {
           'message': "Incorrect Camera Address",
           'status': address.camera_id,
           "expect_input":  "The camera address should be (0, 1) or startwith ('rtsp://', 'rtmp://', 'http://', 'https://')"
           
        }
```

Function that process frame via websocket

```
@app.websocket("/ws")
async def get_stream(websocket: WebSocket):
    
    await websocket.accept()
    
    camera_id = await address(parameter)
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_id)
    try:
        while True:
            frame = camera.frame()
            if frame is not None:
                         
                ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
                await websocket.send_bytes(buffer.tobytes())

                del frame, result
                gc.collect()
                torch.cuda.empty_cache() 
            else:
                print('No frame is rendered') 
                break 

    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        print("Client disconnected")
```

This is how I am calling my function in the `get_stream` function `camera_id = await address(parameter)`

Comment: I'm guessing your `get_stream` function is meant to run forever, so are you asking how you can change which camera stream it returns? Since one is POST and the other is a websocket endpoint, they're responding to different types of requests. You can use a async queue to exchange information, but that requires that both endpoints are handled by the same process - which isn't always likely. You can use the `receive_text` or similar functions on the websocket to receive information on that channel instead, which seems to be more in line with what you want to achieve?

Comment: @MatsLindh I need to pass the camera ID `camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_id)`  before the while loop statement.

but `websocket.receive_text()` , is done within the loop.